# why we can't able to use our own mysql database instead of django database?

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

I have already created a mysql database with the tables table1,table2,table3. I have configured my database details in settings.py file. I jus want to insert the value into table1. I have created a model.py file look like this.

model.py

```
from django.db import models

class table1(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Now i want to insert the value of the field name,phone,email,password which is in the tablename table1. when i run the project, it created the new table with the name of myapp_table1 and inserted the value instead of existing table which i create myself before. But i want to insert those value into already existing table table1. Can anyone explain this concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django will automatically create your database tables with names `{app_name}_{model_name}`. If you want to use a different database then you may use the `db_name` Meta option: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#db-table

Please don't forget that your db tables also need a Primary Key -- django automatically creates one when it creates the tables

Comment: thanks.. I worked with it. Now i understood that concept.. It's working fine.

Comment: You may also want to set the `managed` Meta option, cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#managed